# JavaScript: Check whether variable exists with name given by other variable

Tags: javascript, string, variables, reflection

I know how to check whether a variable in Javascript exists or not. I can simply use

> if (variable == null) { // do something }

to check that it does not exist. Or similarly

> if (typeof variable == 'undefined') {
>       // do something }

But I'm in a slightly different situation: I have a variable named 'myVariable' which takes a string as value.

**Question:** How can I check whether a variable exists with a name equal to the value of myVariable?

**Example:** If we have

> var myVariable = 'car';

how can I check whether a variable exists / is defined with the name 'car'? (Of course in practice we don't know the value of myVariable). I need something like

> if (typeof value of myVariable == 'undefined') { // do something}

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? It’s hardly ever a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Variable" variables in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: I really need it but it's difficult to explain. It's because I'm working on a project which involves different names for one object (depending where this object appears). However, I have to be able to handle all these object with one code (which fits for all the names). The details are difficult, but I can manage everything if I know how to solve the question above. Unfortunately I cannot change the whole naming system because I depend on the system and the other people in the project (I really would like to!).

Comment: Could you give a concrete example, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for null, NaN etc like:

```
if(myVariable) {
    doSomething()
} else {
    doSomething()
}
```

it means, will be false if value is null, undefined, NaN, empty string(""), 0, false

You can save 90% time